# How to sort this dicts by keys?

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary, key

I'm trying to sort these two dictionaries by their keys, how should i do it?

I need to implement an algorithm to sort this.

I tried some sorted algorithms but it did not work.

I know that if I merge them they will be sorted, but I need something to do this for me.

```
FIRST_DICT = {'x': [1, 2, 3],
                  'y': 1,
                  'z': set([1, 2, 3]),
                  'w': 'qweqwe',
                  't': {'a': [1, 2]},
                  'm': [1],
                  'q': 'xzz'}
SECOND_DICT = {'x': [4, 5, 6],
                   'y': 4,
                   'z': set([4, 2, 3]),
                   'w': 'asdf',
                   't': {'a': [3, 2]},
                   'm': "wer",
                   'n': 'x'}
NEW_DICT = {}
```

Also I need to put the sorted keys into this merged function:

```
def merge(first_dict, second_dict, new_dict):
    """This will merge the two dictionfirst_dictries"""
    unique = True
    keys_in_both_lists = conc(first_dict, second_dict, unique)s
    for key in keys_in_both_lists:
        if first_dict.get(key) is None:
            new_dict[key] = second_dict.get(key)
            print "Not found:", key
        elif second_dict.get(key) is None:
            new_dict[key] = first_dict.get(key)
            print "Not found:", key
        elif not isinstance(first_dict[key], type(second_dict[key])):
            new_dict[key] = (first_dict[key], {second_dict[key]})
        elif isinstance(first_dict[key], list):
            new_dict[key] = conc(first_dict[key],
                                 second_dict[key],
                                 unique=False)
        elif isinstance(first_dict[key], set):
            new_dict[key] = first_dict[key] | second_dict[key]
        elif isinstance(first_dict[key], dict):
            new_dict[key] = merge(first_dict[key],
                                  second_dict[key],
                                  {})
        else:
            new_dict[key] = first_dict[key] + second_dict[key]
    return new_dict
```

I expect this:

```
'm': ([1], "wer")}, 'n': 'x', 'q': 'xzz','t': {'a': [1, 2, 3, 2]}, 'w': 'qweqweasdf', 'x': [1,2,3,4,5,6], 'y': 5, 'z': set([1,2,3,4])
```

Comment: You have elements of different types. How do you compare those? For example `([1], "wer")`?

Comment: @CristiFati ```elif not isinstance(first_dict[key], type(second_dict[key])):```, Anyway i need to compare keys, like a>b>c and so on.

Answer (score 0):

There are two different problems here: (1) how to join two dictionaries and (2) how to sort dictionaries.

(1) The operation of joining dictionaries can be straightforward performed using `itertools.groupby` module (take a look at the code below). More info on itertools groupby here: https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby

(2) Dictionaries in Python are unsorted data structures. They cannot be sorted. What I would recommend you is not to use dictionaries and switch to a list of `(key, value)` tuples. Another option is to use `OrderedDict` data structure from the library `collections`. More info here: https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict

The way I would solve the problem:

```
d1 = {'x': [1, 2, 3],
                  'y': 1,
                  'z': set([1, 2, 3]),
                  'w': 'qweqwe',
                  't': {'a': [1, 2]},
                  'm': [1],
                  'q': 'xzz'}
d2 = {'x': [4, 5, 6],
                   'y': 4,
                   'z': set([4, 2, 3]),
                   'w': 'asdf',
                   't': {'a': [3, 2]},
                   'm': "wer",
                   'n': 'x'}


from itertools import groupby        
from collections import OrderedDict

elements = list(d1.items()) + list(d2.items())
elements = sorted(elements, key=lambda x:x[0])
groups = groupby(elements, key=lambda x:x[0])
dict_reduced = []
for k, g in groups:
   dict_reduced.append((k, [x[1] for x in g]))

dict_reduced = OrderedDict(dict_reduced)
```